# How do I add an ActiveX component to my project in Visual C++ 2008

Tags: visual-c++, activex, visual-c++-2008-express

I am just learning Visual C++ and I am used to Visual Basic where I just select the ActiveX component from a list of references.  I can seem to add it anywhere.  If I go to the Project | References, it is all blank.  It only allows me to specify a path and when I specify the path of the AcitveX component, nothing new happens.

I dragged the ActiveX component into Visual C++ and it now shows up in the Object Browser but I cant seem to do anything with it.

I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is a dialog based application then:

> Right click -> Add Active X Component

It displays the list of components. Select the desired one.